# How can I change the order of my widgets in Qt Creator / Designer?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

How can I change the order of my widgets on the top right in Qt Creator / Designer where is says "Object Class"? I tried to drag my widget up by clicking on the name under "Object", and also by clicking on the text under "Class" but neither method worked. I do not want to change the tab order of the widgets, just the order in the designer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the question being asked but, what I want to do is change the order of the actual widgets on the screen but I got into a situation where I couldn't drag the widget around the screen because the destination wasn't visible. I ended up changing the order by editing the UI file directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order is determined firstly by the object hierarchy and secondly by object-name (sorted alphabetically). There is no way to change that structure.

Comment: There may be no way to change them in the UI, but it certainly does not sort them alphabetically by name. For example, in one VerticalLayout I see: "sObject", "cObject", "hObject", in that order.

Comment: @automorphic Yes, it does sort them alphabetically by default. You can easily verify this for yourself by creating a blank form and then dropping a random selection of widgets on it. Of course, some objects have a user-defined order (e.g. layouts, menu items, toolbar buttons, etc), so sorting obviously wouldn't be applied to them.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It normally sorts alphabetically, but strangely orders some items in an unintuitive way (as mentioned above within the Vertical Layout). The first item is last, the 2nd item is first. Crazy.

Comment: @automorphic Maybe it's maintaining insertion order?

Comment: Good guess, but the last one added went into the middle of the list! And since they're ordered intuitively in the file (within the VerticalLayout by their position 1st ,2nd, 3rd), it's only that they are being _displayed_ out of order.

Answer (score 6):

The items in `Object Inspector` panel really are not draggable.

However, you can use `Object Inspector` to highlight an item, which placement you want to change. Then you are free to drag this item **from the form** to any layout **in Object Inspector**.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Also, as the problem is with placing elements in the gui, it turns out that it is actually possible to place elements to the correct place in the form. You need to drag element (or group of elements, such as horisontal layout) from the form and over the form and catch the tiny blue line, then drop there. That blue line is hard to catch because you need to be 1 pixel precise.